# How to remove duplicates from large CSV file ? preferably in r or python

Tags: python, r, csv, duplicates

I have large CSV file ( data size 20 GB) . It contains time series data from sensors and Time columns have multiple duplicate values? How I can I remove those duplicates?

Due to large size of file , I am not able to read it in R and looking for ways to remove duplicates without reading file ( or read in chunk ) ?

Comment: I suggest use [dask.dataframe.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.drop_duplicates)

Comment: but it is not possible without read all data

Comment: If you can't fit it into RAM, you will probably have to go the way of a database...

Comment: Yes, I think it is better to use a database first - assuming they have a reasonably fast connection, the OP could upload it to BigQuery and then use an R package like `bigrquery` to interact with it. For example, they could use `dplyr::distinct()` to remove the duplicates and then save the de-duped version to a fresh table and then use that as a basis for analysis.

Answer (score -1):

you can try reading files using fread from data.table

```
library(data.table)
df<- fread("filename.csv")

##removing duplicates 

df1<- unique(df)
```

I hope your system has sufficient RAM. fread is many times faster than read.csv